# html2canvas is not highlighting the highlighted circles

Tags: d3.js, svg, dc.js, html2canvas

http://4axiz.com/canadian_crime/

in this link, if i select any circle, and then save that state, in the exported image, the highlighted circle is not showing, this is showing the whole svg. Probably html2canvas can't use any css.

To save i used this way:

```js
var xmlString = "";
            var urlParam = "";

            function save_state() {

                var filters = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < dc.chartRegistry.list().length; i++) {
                    var chart = dc.chartRegistry.list()[i];
                    for (var j = 0; j < chart.filters().length; j++) {
                        filters.push({ChartID: chart.chartID(), Filter: chart.filters()[j]});
                    }
                }
                urlParam = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(filters));

                var svgElements = $("#svgContainer").find('svg');
//replace all svgs with a temp canvas
                svgElements.each(function () {
                    var canvas, xml;

                    canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                    canvas.className = "screenShotTempCanvas";
                    //convert SVG into a XML string
                    xml = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(this);

                    // Removing the name space as IE throws an error
                    xml = xml.replace(/xmlns=\"http:\/\/www\.w3\.org\/2000\/svg\"/, '');

                    //draw the SVG onto a canvas
                    canvg(canvas, xml);
                    $(canvas).insertAfter(this);
                    //hide the SVG element
//                        this.className s(= "tempHide";
                    $(this).attr("class", "tempHide");
                    $(this).hide();
                });

                $.ajaxSetup({async: false});

                html2canvas($('#svgContainer'), {
                    onrendered: function (canvas) {
                        var imgString = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                        allowTaint: true
                        var postdata = {'state': urlParam, 'image': imgString}
                        var url = '<?php echo site_url("crime/save_crime_state")?>';
                        $.post(url, postdata, function (data) {
                            if (data.status == "success") {

                                $("#svgContainer").find('.screenShotTempCanvas').remove();
                                $("#svgContainer").find('.tempHide').show().removeClass('tempHide');
                                var myImage = $('<img/>');
                                myImage.attr('class', "groupMediaPhoto");
                                myImage.attr('src', data.filepath);
                                myImage.bind('click', function(){
                                    load_state(urlParam);
                                });
                                myImage.appendTo($('.sidecontainer'));
//                                $(".sidecontainer").append(str);
                            }
                        }, "json");


                    }
                });

                $.ajaxSetup({async: true});

            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, external CSS isn't supported.

Comment: thanks for your kind comment. so what is the way to include css there, as i need to render which are highlighted and this depends on the d3.js core functionality

Comment: It should work if you set the styles in the Javascript code.

Comment: ok, thanks for your kind help